# Modifying data frame with values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I've 2 data frames, `df_a` and `df_b` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
```

df_a

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"Letters": ['E', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'K', 'T', 'X'],
                     "Greek":['epsilon', 'eta', 'omicron', 'nu', 'mu', 
                              'kappa', 'tau', 'chi']})

     Greek Letters
0  epsilon       E
1      eta       H
2  omicron       O
3       nu       N
4       mu       M
5    kappa       K
6      tau       T
7      chi       X
```

df_b

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"Letters": ['Y', 'E', 'N', 'X', 'B']})
df_b["Greek"] = ""

  Letters Greek
0       Y      
1       E      
2       N      
3       X      
4       B
```

I want to fill in column 'Greek' in `df_b` using corresponding values from `df_a` and I can do that using nested loops as follows:

```
for i, row in df_a.iterrows():
    temp1 = row['Letters']
    for k, row in df_b.iterrows():
        temp2 = row['Letters']
        if temp1 == temp2:
            df_b.loc[k, "Greek"]=df_a.loc[i, "Greek"]
```

df_b

```
Letters    Greek
0       Y         
1       E  epsilon
2       N       nu
3       X      chi
4       B
```

First, I'm wondering if I can achieve the same result more efficiently using `merge`, `zip`, `join` or the other concatenation functions. Second, if I provide a matching `else` to the `if` statement, as follows:

`else: df_b.loc[k, "Greek"] = float('nan')`

I expected this would fill in the empty cells with `NaN` and not modify the other cells. Instead, I get something like:

df_b

```
  Letters Greek
0       Y   NaN
1       E   NaN
2       N   NaN
3       X   chi
4       B   NaN
```

I appreciate your thoughts on the 2 points. Any additional feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest method would be to set 'Letters' as the index for df_a and then call `map`:

```
In [11]:

df_a = df_a.set_index('Letters')
df_b['Greek'] = df_b['Letters'].map(df_a['Greek'])
df_b
Out[11]:
  Letters    Greek
0       Y      NaN
1       E  epsilon
2       N       nu
3       X      chi
4       B      NaN
```

Just to demonstrate the flaw in your loop it is worth printing out what happens:

```
In [17]:

for i, row in df_a.iterrows():
    temp1 = row['Letters']
    for k, row in df_b.iterrows():
        temp2 = row['Letters']
        if temp1 == temp2:
            print("match i:", i, "k:", k, "letter:", temp2)
        else:
            print("no match i:", i, "k:", k, "letter:", temp2)
no match i: 0 k: 0 letter: Y
match i: 0 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 0 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 0 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 0 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 1 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 1 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 1 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 1 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 1 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 2 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 2 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 2 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 2 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 2 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 3 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 3 k: 1 letter: E
match i: 3 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 3 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 3 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 4 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 4 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 4 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 4 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 4 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 5 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 5 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 5 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 5 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 5 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 6 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 6 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 6 k: 2 letter: N
no match i: 6 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 6 k: 4 letter: B
no match i: 7 k: 0 letter: Y
no match i: 7 k: 1 letter: E
no match i: 7 k: 2 letter: N
match i: 7 k: 3 letter: X
no match i: 7 k: 4 letter: B
```

So although you make the initial match, you loop over those rows again and blitz them with `NaN` rather than skipping them.

**Timings**

```
In [22]:

df_a = df_a.set_index('Letters')
%timeit df_b['Greek'] = df_b['Letters'].map(df_a['Greek'])

1000 loops, best of 3: 710 µs per loop
In [24]:

%%timeit 
for i, row in df_a.iterrows():
    temp1 = row['Letters']
    for k, row in df_b.iterrows():
        temp2 = row['Letters']
        if temp1 == temp2:
            df_b.loc[k, "Greek"]=df_a.loc[i, "Greek"]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop
```

Calling map here is nearly 18 times faster, this is a vectorised function and will scale much better.

Comment: Thanks greatly. I see clearly now, esp. with the printouts. In terms of efficiency in this given example, how does the nested loops and map stack? Perhaps you can talk in terms of big O.

Comment: Well your solution is O2 as you loop over 2 loops, this I suspect will be between On and nlogn, `map` is a vectorised function so will operate on the whole array rather than a row value at a time

Comment: Thanks for the time analysis! I applied map in my actual dataset and for some reason my target column is not being filled in. I've something like this `df_1 = df_1.set_index("Visit"); df_2['Result'] = df_2['Visit'].map(df_1['Result'])`. Not that you can glean much from that. Any random thought why the Result column in df_2 might come in as blank? Before applying `map`, I ensured 'Visit' columns in both data frames contain [unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352369/pandas-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects) using `groupby`.

Comment: Try printing each line to see what is being returned, also does it work when running your loop code? One possibility is you have no matches or you may have done something prior to the operation but I can't guess what

Comment: Oops, an extra whitespace somehow maybe into one of the rows. Once I corrected that, the values came roaring in as supposed.